# Flex 4: Get the pressed object

Tags: apache-flex, colors

My Skin:

```
<s:DataGroup id="view1" width="100%" height="100%" itemRenderer="views.itemRenderers.BrickItemRenderer" dataProvider="{hostComponent.createArray()}">
    <s:layout>
      <s:TileLayout /> 
    </s:layout>
  </s:DataGroup>
```

My View for create object 'bricks'

```
[Bindable]
    public function createArray():ArrayCollection
    {
      var dataBrick:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();  
      var data:DataAboutBrick;
      for (var x:int = 0; x < 5; x++)
        for (var y:int = 0; y < 7; y++)
        { 
          data = new DataAboutBrick();
          data.x = 0;
          data.y = 0;
          data.color = colorBrick;
          dataBrick.addItem(data);
        }      
      return dataBrick;
    }
```

Class DataAboutBrick for saved data about object:

```
public class DataAboutBrick extends Object
  {
    public function DataAboutBrick()
    {
      super();
    }

    public var x:int;
    public var y:int;
    public var color:uint = 0xFF0000;
    public var id:String;
  }
```

Mediator:

```
private function btnBricknew_clickHandler(event:BaseBrickEvent):void
{      
  view.colorBrick = model.currentColor;
}
```

Mediator change color all object when clicked on object. And need only change the color of the object to be pressed.

Comment: So what is your question? How to get the BrickItemRenderer that was clicked inside of the Tilelayout? I would stay away from bindable functions that return a dataprovider, this is asking for trouble :) There might be cases where you would just suddenly get a fresh new dataprovider and would not even know about it. Since you have mediators, create the dataprovider there and pass it to the view without any bindings, the classics MVC style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Brick and BrickSkin defined, you can define the functionality to change the color in BrickItemRenderer as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<spark:DefaultComplexItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:spark="spark.skins.spark.*">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    [Bindable("dataChanged")]
    override public function set data(value:Object):void
    {
        super.data = value;
        var brick:Brick = new Brick();
        brick.colorBrick = value.color;
        brick.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, brickClicked,false,0,true);
        this.addElement(brick);
    }

    private function brickClicked(event:Event)
    {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        data.color = 0x00FF00;// Please make sure your color variable defined in DataAboutBrick.as is Bindable.
    }
    ]]></fx:Script>
</spark:DefaultComplexItemRenderer>
```